# What does the allocation graph show in Xamarin Profiler?

Tags: performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, xamarin-profiler

Xamarin Profiler documentation states *"Currently the allocations graph is **the total number** of allocations and NOT the size of the heap at that point in time. In a sense, it **will never go down**, it will only ever increase.*" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=windows)

Is this piece of doc correct? I thought that the graph shows the working set memory usage, and it can go down when memory is released (see the pictures below). But if the doc is correct, how can those drops be explained?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal memory conscious application that the allocation graph would essentially maintain a 0 slope. In reality, this decline is normal. It's normal for the allocation graph to fall back down because it has increased before(except for caches, and even those may fall back down when purged on memory pressure).

And the "Currently" in the document may indicate that the allocation graph will only appear under the specific ideal conditions stated in the document.